# If statement is ignored

Tags: java, if-statement

I am making a simple matchmaker as a learning project in JAVA. My program so far just asks a few questions, but I wanted to do gender specific questions, so I asked for their sex (m or f) and then attempted to add a message that only showed if sex was m. The dialog should say "well done, you are male!". Else it restarts method. Every time, no matter what I type it restarts the program.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        setVars();
    }

    public static void setVars(){
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?");
        String sAge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your age?");
        String sex = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your sex?\n(Enter  m or f)");

        if (sex == "m"){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well done, you are male.\nKeep Going!");
        }
        int age = Integer.parseInt(sAge);
        String chars = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name three charectaristics");
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings should ALWAYS compared using `equals()` method.

Comment: `"m"` is _not_ the same as `sex`, even if the value of `sex` is `"m"`. String comparisons should be done using `equals()` (as mentioned above), which compares the equalness, not the identity.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if ( "m".equalIgnoreCase(sex))
```

you should use equals for comparing string value and == for checking their references

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
if ("m".equals(sex)) {
  //
}
```

== compares objects' addresses / references
.equals compares objects' values

Comment: It should be `"m".equals(sex)` because `sex` is possible to be `null`

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you dont' compare strings with `==`, you have to compare them with the `equals()` method on `String`. String has two variants of this method: `equals()` which is case sensitive, and `equalsIgnoreCase()`, which is case insensitive. In the examples below, you can use either one.

Try this:

```
if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase("m") {
    ...
}
```

Or to guard against nulls...

```
if("m".equalsIgnoreCase(sex)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because `String` is an object not a data type like `int` when it comes to compare two Strings it is done by `.equals()` method:

```
package example;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        setVars();
    }
    public static void setVars(){
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?");
        String sAge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your age?");
        String sex = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your sex?\n(Enter  m or f)");
        if (sex.equals("m")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well done, you are male.\nKeep Going!");
        }
        int age = Integer.parseInt(sAge);
        String chars = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name three charectaristics");
    }
}
```